# systemd-logind uses 80-90% CPU

Tags: 14.04, systemd-logind

After logging in, `cgmanager` and `systemd-logind` use about 80-90% CPU.

I killed `cgmanager`, now `systemd-logind` is using 80-90% CPU.

My system is Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS.
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug, please watch https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1750013/comments/16, forwarding to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1303649 from comment #17.